# Mapbox layer click event splitting up data source feature and only returning part of it

Tags: mapbox, geojson

I'm a little confused on how mapbox maps layers to data sources. When I add a data source:

```
// polyData is a geoJSON collection of ~ 18 geoJSON objects, each for a unique 'county'
map.addSource(name, {
  type: "geojson",
  data: polyData,
  promoteId: 'county'
});
```

And then make a layer for it:

```
map.addLayer(
  {
    id: `county-active-fill`,
    type: "fill",
    source: "county",
    layout: {
      visibility: "visible"
    },
    paint: {
      "fill-color": "#87d6e3",
      "fill-opacity": 0.25,
    }
  },
);
```

And then register a click event handler for it:

```
map.on("click", "county-active-fill", (event) => {
  const features = event.features;
  console.log(features);
})
```

This "feature" is different based on where in the Polygon of a specific county you click. Inspecting the data, sometimes the geometry has 92 coordinates, and sometimes it has 237 coordinates - and since I'm attempting to use `turf.js` to do polygon / intersection / area math, the values are different for the exact same region clicked, depending where in that region you clicked.

When I inspect the data source in that method, using `querySourceFeatures`:

```
map.on("click", "county-active-fill", (event) => {
  const features = this.map.querySourceFeatures("county", {
    filter: ["==", "county", event.features[0].properties.county]
  });
  console.log(features);
})
```

There are *four* return results, even though my initial data source only gave it one feature for this county. It seems to split my one data value up into four... tiles? with different values for x, y, z:

```
tile: {z: 8, x: 53, y: 96}
tile: {z: 8, x: 52, y: 96}
tile: {z: 8, x: 53, y: 95}
tile: {z: 8, x: 52, y: 95}
```

These are different from the geometry points, which contain 92, 237, 6, and 95 points respectively.

And indeed, in that initial click handler with `event.features`, they included a `_x`, `_y`, and `_z` properties that seem to line up to these four individual data source "tiles".

My question is... why is it splitting up my single polygon into four separate instances on the map, and how can I get it so that clicking on that region of the map returns the *entire* original county polygon, not this weird partial that it's giving me - such that my polygon math will work correctly?